# links in a pdf open in a new window/tab

Tags: pdf, hyperlink

I have a PDF with HTML like the following embedded into it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <body>
        <embed src="a.pdf" width="800px" height="1050px">
    </body>
</html>
```

`a.pdf` cointains links inside like "https://www.google.com.ph/"

I want it so that when the user clicks on the links in the PDF, it will open in a new tab or window?

Do i need Javascript or some other language?

Answer (score 0):

Try using an `iframe` for this.  It requires PDF support in the browser of course, which is not universal, so you may want to also offer a download link of some kind.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<body>
    <iframe src="a.pdf" width="800px" height="1050px"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: then whats next buddy? what should i add so that when iclick on the link it will be open in another tab

Comment: A link can open in new tab by setting `target="_blank"`, such as: `<a href="a.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>`.  Also, welcome to StackOverflow!  Normally we try to keep a single question per page here, so that other users can more easily search for specific questions.

Comment: yes i know that buddy but may problem is the LINK is INSIDE the PDF file